# Linq Expression in nHibernate

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, interface, repository

I have an interface, called IRepository.
One of the methods in this interface is:

```
IEnumerable<T> FindByQuery(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
```

I then have (for example) an IUserRepository, that implements IRepository.

In my implementation of IUserRepository, currently called LinqToSqlUserRepository, i have implemented the FindByQuery method like so:

```
public IEnumerable<PurchaseOrder> FindByQuery(Expression<Func<PurchaseOrder, bool>> predicate)
    {
        using (var db = new NavisionDataContext())
            return db.PurchaseOrders.Where(predicate)
                .ToList();
    }
```

My question is, in the fullness of time, I intend to use nHibernate (or another ORM)

Would I be able to use Linq-To-Nhibernate to implement my method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not? Linq to hibernate starts work deeper then this.